# How to get data from json one by one?

Tags: json

I have json datatype

`{"email":"mikekhlau@gmail.com","contact":[{"contact_name":"Mike Lau","contact_no":"019-3331976"},{"contact_name":"Jason Lau","contact_no":"013-2711188"},{"contact_name":"Margaret Lau","contact_no":"019-3122281"}]}`

How can I get email, contact_name and contact_no?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the language you're using. Also, consider looking up a basic tutorial on using JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var json = {"email":"mikekhlau@gmail.com","contact":[{"contact_name":"Mike Lau","contact_no":"019-3331976"},{"contact_name":"Jason Lau","contact_no":"013-2711188"},{"contact_name":"Margaret Lau","contact_no":"019-3122281"}]}
```

You can get data by..

```
json.email
```

"mikekhlau@gmail.com"

```
json.contact[0].contact_name
```

"Mike Lau"

```
json.contact[0].contact_no
```

"019-3331976"

Answer (score 1):

```
    try {
             JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(strJson);

             String email = jsonRootObject .getString("email");
             //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains JSONObjects
             JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("contacts");

             //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
             for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    String contact_name = jsonObject.getString("contact_name");            
    String contact_no= jsonObject.getString("contact_no");            
             }

          } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
       }

use the above code
```